# Label takes long time to change

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem with my winform app in C#.
In program, i have a label as statusbar and a method like this:

```
private void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblStatus.Text = "Please wait...";
    /*
    Code here
    */
}
```

my code process taking a few second but after processing the code, text of label will change and i want it happening before that.

Note: I am an amateur in programming and i cant understand english very well, please explain your solution simply. thank you.

Comment: You should not execute long-running tasks on the GUI thread.

Comment: @SamLeach That may answer the question in his title, but if you read the question, he's not really asking about `endl` at all.

Comment: use `Timer` or `Thread` you can't see whatever else

Comment: @Abdullah Completely unhelpful.

Comment: Add `lblStatus.Update();`  Gives you a while to start learning how to use the BackgroundWorker or Task classes to do this the right way, as long as the code doesn't take more than 5 seconds anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to hack this using a repaint event by calling Update or Refresh, but the real solution is using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for longer operations.

This is not easy stuff, you should find a tutorial for it in a language you understand perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In winform application (but also in all GUI application) it's not recommended execute long task in the GUI thread. For solving your problem you must use Thread([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can find the complete mdsn reference).
If you want update the Label from another Thread you' ll do a Cross threading operation. For more information take a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

All the code is always ran and completed before any changes are made to the UI. This is just the basic logic of WinForms and WPF.

You can use **"BackgroundWorker"**, so the longer code is run on another thread. This way you can freely edit the UI-elements while the longer code is still running.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net 4.5, you can use `await` and `async` rather than `BackgroundWorker`.

You would create an `async` method that returns a Task, and inside that method use `Task.Run()` to start the background work.

Here's an example. You'd do all the slow work in the lambda passed to `Task.Run()` where I've commented "Do all your slow work here":

```
private async void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblStatus.Text = "Please wait...";

    await doSomeWorkAsynchronously();

    lblStatus.Text = "Work completed";
}

private async Task doSomeWorkAsynchronously()
{
    await Task.Run(()=>
    {
        // Do all your slow work here.
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // Simulate slow work.
    });
}
```

I think this is a bit easier than using `BackgroundWorker`.

Note that if all your "slow" methods were already `async` (e.g. if you are using [asynchronous file I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) then you might just be able to `await` each of your async operations rather than having to create your own task via `Task.Run()`.

You can also return a value from the background task. Suppose you wanted to return a string with which to update the label when the background task had completed. You could do that as follows:

```
private async void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblStatus.Text = "Please wait...";
    lblStatus.Text = await doSomeWorkAsynchronously();
}

private async Task<string> doSomeWorkAsynchronously()
{
    return await Task.Run(()=>
    {
        // Do all your slow work here.
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // Simulate slow work.
        return "The task completed.";
    });
}
```